# React Router v6 - access nested routes and correct way to handle an url written by hand

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I'm building a bibliothek service using mainly `react`, `redux-toolkit` and `react-router`.

I would like to add a dynamic route, which is a page that displays the details of the clicked book. This route should be reachable from the Home page, where I have some cover book images, and the Catalogue page, where the entire list is showed. I'm quite confused about this.

1. The most important. There is something that I miss. I tried the following, but doesn't work. I tried to `navigate` to the `/catalogue/:bookId` from the Home page and the Catalogue page, but it doesn't render the correct component. I think I misunderstood the sense of the children inside the route object, any suggestion? Should I use the `<Outlet />` and which is the correct flow for this?

Part of the *router.tsx*

```
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: 'catalogue',
        element: <Catalogue />,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/catalogue/:bookId',
            element: <BookDetails />
          }
        ]
      },
```

Part of the `<Catalogue />` component in which I render a  for each book in the list.

```
       {
          list.map((book, i) => {
            return (
              <BookCard
                book={book}
                key={`book-${i}`} />
            )
          })
        }
```

`<BookCard />` component

```
const BookCard = ({ book }: {
  book: IBook;
}) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(exploredBook(book));
    navigate(`/catalogue/${book.id}`)
  }

  return (
    <Col>
      <Card className="book-card">
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card.Img 
              className="book-img"
              variant="top"
              src={book.imageLink}
              alt={`${book.title} book cover`} />            
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title as={Link} to={`/catalogue/${book.id}`}>{book.title}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle>{book.author}, {book.year}</Card.Subtitle>
              {  
                book.book_status.copies <= 0
                  ? <Badge bg="danger">Out of stock</Badge>
                  : <Badge bg="success">{book.book_status.copies} copies available</Badge>
              }
              <CatalogueActions book={book} />
              <Card.Link href={book.link} target='_blank'>
                <small>More about <em>{book.title}</em> on Wikipedia</small>
              </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  )
};

export default BookCard;
```

2. My second question is: when the user arrives on the details of the book, the url should be something like `/localhost:3000/catalogue/o23ifo2eifj8249g2g24g`. But if the user, write by hand the url and inserts a random id, the page will render nevertheless the content. How can I prevent the rendering of the content? My simple solution would be, make a search in the `database` using the hook `useParams()` for the written id: if exist, the corresponding book is rendered, if doesn't exist, a 404 page is rendered. Is there a better simplier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current routes config:

```
{
  path: '/',
  element: <Home />,
},
{
  path: 'catalogue',
  element: <Catalogue />,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/catalogue/:bookId', // <-- or simply ":bookId"
      element: <BookDetails />
    }
  ]
},
```

A ***nested*** route on `path="/catalogue/:bookId"` is rendered.

> Should I use the `<Outlet />` and which is the correct flow for this?

Yes, in this configuration the `Catalogue` component necessarily should render an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their content into. This is the use case where you want to render the `Catalogue` ***and*** `BookDetails` simultaneously.

Catalogue Example:

```
{list.map((book, i) => {
  return (
    <BookCard
      book={book}
      key={`book-${i}`} />
    )
  })
}
...

<Outlet />
```

If this isn't the case and you want `Catalogue` and `BookDetails` to render each on their own independent pages then the routes should be unnested.

Example:

```
{
  path: '/',
  element: <Home />,
},
{
  path: 'catalogue',
  element: <Catalogue />,
},
{
  path: '/catalogue/:bookId',
  element: <BookDetails />
}
```

or

```
{
  path: '/',
  element: <Home />,
},
{
  path: 'catalogue',
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      element: <Catalogue />
    },
    {
      path: ':bookId',
      element: <BookDetails />
    }
  ]
},
```

> When the user arrives on the details of the
> book, the url should be something like
> `"/catalogue/o23ifo2eifj8249g2g24g"`. Iif the user,
> write by hand the url and inserts a random id, the page will render
> nevertheless the content. How can I prevent the rendering of the
> content? My simple solution would be, make a search in the database
> using the hook `useParams()` for the written id: if exist, the
> corresponding book is rendered, if doesn't exist, a 404 page is
> rendered. Is there a better simpler solution?

This is a standard practice to validate dynamic route path parameters and either redirect a user to a 404 page or to conditionally render some fallback UI by the `BookDetails` page when consuming an invalid `bookId` value.